# How to test a React app with mock data from GraphQL?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql-js, apollo

I have a simple React app where I test a component that gets user-data from **GraphQL** in the `'user'` prop. The app is written in **TypeScript** and I already generate the type-definitions from the introspection query.

How can I test that component without having to manually mock every field of the user? I already have the Graphql schema from the type generation so that should be easy, right?

There is this article http://graphql.org/blog/mocking-with-graphql/#mocking-is-easy-with-a-type-system that says it just takes 2 lines of code, but I cannot get it to work and I can't find a proper documentation for the `mockServer`.

Then there is the graphql-tools (http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/mocking.html) but none of those examples really work ...

I generate the schema with `apollo-codegen introspect-schema`.

Is there any **working** example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/easygraphql-mock

Just pass the schema that you have and it is going to mock all the types and fields. After you mock it you can access the type you want.